# How to copy a file to a Docker container before starting/running it?

Tags: docker

I'm starting with a docker image that is already built.
I would like to do this

1. Create a docker container from this image. (Don't start)
2. Copy a file to this container
3. Start the container

How can this be achieved. It looks like if i run the following commands the file doesn't end up in the container

1. docker create --name my_container my_image
2. docker cp file my_container:/tmp/file
3. docker start my_container

Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: An PR like https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14429 shows it should work though. So does http://stackoverflow.com/a/32126677/6309

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to create a new image from a Dockerfile that inherit from the one that is already built, and the use the COPY tag:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM my_image
COPY file /tmp/file
```

Finally, build that new Dockerfile:

```
$ docker build -t new_image .
```

Comment: This answer and the answer on here both work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32126677/6309

Answer (score 0):

Create a dir (e.g. init) put your sql or shell script in it.
bind mount the dir ~/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this option but I do not recommend this for production, you can mount it as an external volume like  -v /path/yourlocalfolder:/path/inside/container, this works for files or folders.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't exactly answer the question, but can also mount the desired file to the container. The file will be created inside the container if non-existent or will be replaced if existing in the docker container.